# How can I redirect many urls to a new format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

For example, I have a url structure like this:

```
/company/articles/{month}/{articleName}
```

and I now want to redirect all existing links to something like this:

```
/articles/{articleName}
```

I thought I could do something like this, but it's not redirecting.

```
routes.Add("articles",
                new Route("company/articles/{month}/{articleName}",
                    new RedirectRouteHandler("articles/{articleName}")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [RouteMagic library](https://github.com/haacked/routemagic) to do such things easy. you can find an example in Phil Haack's [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx).

Comment: I found this library but thought there might be an easier way as I only need this feature